# Cognos Analytics: QE-DEF-0459 on a CASE WHEN expression

Tags: sql, cognos

I am trying to create a new data item based on certain conditions. I did run across a couple of threads regarding this very issue, but I either don't know what syntax I need or I can't find where my syntax error is located.  I am receiving a parsing error: QE-DEF-0459, QE-DEF-0260, and QE-DEF-0261
for the below code.

```
CASE
    WHEN [Shipping].[Wave PARM].[MISC_STAT_CODE_2] =2 AND [ASRS_Lines] IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Sent'
    WHEN [Shipping].[Wave PARM].[MISC_STAT_CODE_2] !=2 AND [ASRS_Lines] IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Not Sent'
    ELSE NULL
END
```

I can't seem to figure out how to correct this error and any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have also tried...

```
IF  [Shipping].[Wave PARM].[MISC_STAT_CODE_2] = 2 AND [ASRS_Lines] IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Sent'
    ELSE IF [Shipping].[Wave PARM].[MISC_STAT_CODE_2] != 2 AND [ASRS_Lines] IS NOT NULL
        THEN 'Not Sent'
    ELSE NULL
END
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why are you using parentheses around values?  Remove those.  If numeric, just delete them.  If strings, add single quotes instead.  For example `THEN 'Sent'`...

Comment: I noticed on several websites people using parentheses.  I was initially using single quotes for those values but was getting the same error.

Comment: No worries, I haven't used `congnos`, but it just looked off.  This might help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29355059/using-case-when-in-cognos-data-item

Comment: That was the first thread I saw.  I have attempted both suggestions, none of which worked for me.

Comment: You need use `<>`, not `!=`, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one item that Cognos may take issue with there. Try <> instead of !=.

If that doesn't fix the problem, try deleting that data item and validating the report. If it still fails, that data item is not where the problem is.

Comment: Thank you.  It seems to be the case that my detail filters are throwing the error.

Comment: My fallback plan when I can't identify what's wrong is to delete items one-at-a-time and validate after each delete.  When the report validates, I know the last thing I deleted was the problem.

Comment: If you don't mind my asking.  If I want to create a data item that needs to be filtered in and of itself, do I need to create a detail filter, or define the scope within the data item?

Comment: That depends on what you mean.  If you want to filter the query to a subset of the values in that data item, you need to create a detail filter.  If you want to list a subset of the values in that data item and replace the rest with a default value, or to otherwise transform the values, you'll want to use a CASE statement to create the grouping.  But this should probably have been a separate question with sample input and output data included.